# How to filter 3 level wpf treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, treeview, dataset

Trying to filter level 2 and 3 nodes on a wpf treeview that is bound to a dataset.

I have tried using a value converter on the visibility property of the nodes but being a HierarchicalDataTemplate the converter isn't called.

```
                <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataSetProvider" MethodName="GetDataSet" ObjectType="{x:Type local:DataSetCreator}"/>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="SymbolTemplate">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SymbolName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FamilyTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Fam2Sym}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SymbolTemplate}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FamilyName}" />
                        <TextBlock><Run Text=" ("/><Run Text=")"/></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Categorytemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Cat2Fam}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FamilyTemplate}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedName}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <TreeView x:Name="archTree" DataContext="{StaticResource dataSetProvider}" ItemsSource="{Binding RvtCat}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Categorytemplate}"/>
```

I'm trying to filter a wpf treeview where if the level 2 OR 3 nodes match a string filter both levels are shown. I can't seem to find a way to do this. I've searched google but haven't found any similar questions. Suggestions?